# How do you edit the facebook app support email?

Tags: facebook, email

I need to edit the support email for a Facebook application.

It appears the support email is the email I used when I created my facebook profile  (ie a personal email).

I can edit the "Contact Email" to be a generic company contact info, but cannot edit support email...  and I dont want them emailing me on my personal yahoo account I never check.

Any help would be great, I embedded a snapshot (nvm cannot post image because i do not have enough rep)  If it will let me post a link to it, here it is...

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9de0cffc7fdbbaf8&resid=9DE0CFFC7FDBBAF8!459&parid=9DE0CFFC7FDBBAF8!458&authkey=!ACTNlATIAH9PU-w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appId}/summary` just change the "*Contact Email*" field and click Save, go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appId}/advanced` and update the "*User Support Email*" and click Save.  It propagates pretty quickly.

Comment: Lifesaver... I searched for forever for this and must have just missed it.  Too bad they are not in the same spot!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer:
In the edit app page open the tab "App Details"
or open "https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appId}/appdetails"

Here you can find the field "User Support Email:", edit and save, so simple!